# How do i assign colors in javascript from nth-child()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

My main goal is to optimize the sass script using javascript, and my plan is to assign different background colors in the nth-child() using for loop.

But I have searched through many tutorials but I can't find any solutions for it.

```js
var mainColors = ["#1D659D", "#B25353", "#A12456", "#919191", "#7a3091"];
var subColors = ["#2C8AD4", "#FF7777", "#D63475", "#707070", "#b146d1"];

function colorPicker() {
  for (var i = 0; i < mainColors.length; i++) {
    console.log(mainColors[i]);
    console.log(subColors[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.Wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  h1 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      background: #1D659D;
      border-color: #2C8AD4;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: #B25353;
      border-color: #FF7777;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      background: #A12456;
      border-color: #D63475;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      background: #919191;
      border-color: #707070;
    }
    &:nth-child(5) {
      background: #7a3091;
      border-color: #b146d1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correctly using loop now what?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! What is your question precisely?

Comment: You can create multiple class in css and later you can keep the classes as an array in javascript. then you can use those.

Comment: Do you want to generate CSS rules to be loaded as .css file or directly assign styles to elements within the browser?

Comment: I want to assign the colors without using nth-child(), instead using javascript

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you are trying to iterated the colors and set the colors, bellow is the code I have added, this should work for you.

**EDIT**

Thanks for correcting my @try-catch-finally, `querySelectorAll()` will return array, so for selecting specific elements we should use `querySelector()`.

```
function colorPicker(){
for(var i = 0; i < mainColors.length; i++){
    document.querySelector('div:nth-child('+i+')').style.background = mainColors[i];
    document.querySelector('div:nth-child('+i+')').style.borderColor = subColors[i];
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why doesn't the color appear on the page, do I need to execute the function? If so where?

Comment: yes you will need to execute the function, execute the function once the document and the css is loaded.

Comment: I found out that there is an error and it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined
    at main.js:5

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns an array of elements, thus the access `<array>.style` is wrong. It has to be `querySelector()`.

Comment: I have changed querySelectorAll() in to querySelector() but now the error says:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at colorPicker (main.js:6)

Comment: if you are using `document.querySelector('div:nth-child('+i+')')` make it `document.querySelector('div:nth-child('+(i+1)+')')` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can apply,

```
var mainColors = ["#1D659D", "#B25353", "#A12456", "#919191", "#7a3091"];

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), i;
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
   divs[i].style.background = mainColors[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
    div:nth-child(1) {
      background: #1D659D;
      border-color: #2C8AD4;
    }
    div:nth-child(2) {
      background: #B25353;
      border-color: #FF7777;
    }
    div:nth-child(3) {
      background: #A12456;
      border-color: #D63475;
    }
    div:nth-child(4) {
      background: #919191;
      border-color: #707070;
    }
    div:nth-child(5) {
      background: #7a3091;
      border-color: #b146d1;
    }
```

```html
<div>111</div>
<div>222</div>
<div>333</div>
<div>444</div>
<div>555</div>
```

Your CSS is not correct.

Comment: This is not CSS, it is SASS, it is an extension of CSS that enables you to use things like variables, nested rules, inline imports and more. It also helps to keep things organized and allows you to create style sheets faster. https://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/what-is-sass-111517618